# Different geometric figures from trapezoids

Tags: geometry, algorithms

I have recently bought a very interesting a Brazilian kit to my kid to build mosaics:

[image: this figure is from http://prorum.com/index.php/555/brinquedos-especificos-desenvolver-habilidades-matematicas?show=2002#a2002]

It is easy to see that I am able to generate equilateral triangles, hexagons, parallelograms, Rhombuses etc. Furthermore, it is easy to see that the base angles are equal to 60 degrees. **I wonder if there are other interesting geometric figures that can be built using this kit.** If the bases angles of the basic trapezoid were equal to 45 degrees the Rhombus that I built would be a square. However, until now I am not able to build a square using this kit. **Are there geometric algorithms that can be used to study this kind of problem?**

EDIT:

**What cannot be made with this kit? How can I prove this statement?**

Comment: "Interesting" is a fairly subjective term. Personally, I'd be much more interested in knowing what *cant* be made, and how such a statement could be proven

Comment: I tried to edit the question in order to consider this much more interesting formulation of the problem!

Comment: You can form a hierarchical tiling using the inflation rule described [here](http://euler.slu.edu/escher/index.php/Aperiodic_Tessellations#Substitution_Tilings) for the so-called 'half hex tiling' which is an aperiodic tiling which covers the entire plane quasiperiodically.

Comment: @DanRust: I was just going to mention the ["sphinx" rep-tile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rep-tile), myself. :)

Comment: I knew about the fractals such as the Sierpinski triangle (and that it can be generated by contractions, for example), but I have never heard about the jargon "rep-tiles" before. This is by itself a really beautiful world.

Comment: (+1) Each tile has (only) $60$- and $120$-degree internal angles at a vertex, so any figure made by placing tiles edge to edge has internal angles that are an integer multiple of $60$ degrees. Particularly, right angles are impossible by placing tiles edge to edge.